# Shutdown pc after shutdown Spring Boot app programatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I've a particular use case. I've a Spring boot application on my Raspberry. This app is automatically srted at the startup of the Raspberry. I'd like to send a remote command to reboot or shutdown the Raspberry but I need that first my Spring Boot app is closed correclty.

This app use H2Database and SmsLib that take a bit to shutdown (10/20 seconds).

My idea is to intercept the remote request, then try to shutdown programatically the app with:

```
applicationContext.close();
```

then in a my custom ApplicationListener I read the command that I should execute (reboot or halt) and I do:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");
```

this is the relevant part of my contextClosedEvent:

```
@Component
public class ContextClosedHandler implements        ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {
private String commandToExecute;
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
try {
        if (commandToExecute != null) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToExecute);
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("Errore durante l'esecuzione del comando <" + commandToExecute + ">", e);
    }

}
```

However I think this is not the right way at 100%. I should be sure to reboot or shutdown my Raspberry only when all stuffs in my app are terminate (connection with db, listeners, handler, ecc). Have you a better idea?

THanks!

Comment: It would be better to have an external script that tells your application to shut down, waits for it, and then reboots.

Comment: no way to manage this inside the main app in a more reliable way?

Comment: For starters, it'd be a nightmare to test and maintain. Separation of concerns. Presumably you want this service starting on boot anyway?

Comment: Yes, it should start on boot anyway

Comment: Then use an init script, and shut down your Boot app as part of the normal shutdown routine.

Comment: Can you post a full reply with some link? Thanks